# Does MediaCodec always give 16-bit audio output?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm using Android's MediaCodec class to read raw data from audio files. That works just fine.

The problem is that I don't know if it's safe to assume that the output data will always be 16-bit?

I can tell, experimentally, that the output *is* 16-bit, but I don't know how to check that at runtime. The MediaCodec documentation doesn't appear to tell me. The MediaFormat `KEY_CHANNEL_MASK` could tell me, but MediaCodec doesn't appear to set those flags. It sets the sample rate, and the mime-type, but nothing that can tell me the bit-size explicitly.

I suppose that given the difference between presentation times of subsequent blocks, and the sample rate, I should be able to calculate it, but that doesn't seem very satisfactory.

Is there a way to tell, or is it written somewhere that I don't have to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently the output is always 16 bit in stock Android. If that changes in the future we'll add an additional format key that specifies the format. Note that `KEY_CHANNEL_MASK` would only tell you which channels are included (e.g. left, right, center, etc), not the sample format.

Comment: So, if I assume 16-bit that will be future proof?

Comment: Yes, that should be safe.

Comment: 16 bit is already  *not* future proof. Since 24bit and other formats are already supported

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. If you have 24 bit PCM (WAV) files, it will give you 24 bit audio. And seemingly no way to determine this. I have added a question here [MediaCodec and 24 bit PCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246737/mediacodec-and-24-bit-pcm)